# Spring cannot find a bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle

I'm learning Spring as it seems to be a very powerful framework. I've already did many getting started guides and now I'm trying with [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/). In it, all classes are put in the same package, but to make it more interesting I tried using different packages according to the class (entity, controller, etc.). I was about to test it before the **Testing a REST Service** section but got an error building the application. This is how my project is structured:

[image: project structure]

The only difference with the classes in the tutorial is the marked `ServletInitializer` which comes with the [initializr utility](https://start.spring.io) (actually I used the one that comes with STS, but it's the same). As far as I understand, it has nothing to do with the problem so the content of this class is irrelevant.

Another minor difference with the tutorial is that the `Application` class here is called `RestServicesApplication` but the content is the same.

When I try to build the application (using Gradle's `bootRun` instead of Maven) I got the following error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method init in com.example.restservices.RestServicesApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.repository.AccountRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.repository.AccountRepository' in your configuration.

:bootRun FAILED
```

So I tried to annotate `AccountRepository` with `@Bean` but it gives me a compilation error saying that the annotation is disallowed for that location. Next I tried with the `@Component` annotation (also on `BookmarkRepository`) and adding `@ComponentScan("com.example")` in `RestServicesApplication`. After that the error remains but the message changed to

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.controller.BookmarkRestController required a bean of type 'com.example.repository.BookmarkRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.repository.BookmarkRepository' in your configuration.

:bootRun FAILED
```

I added `@Component` annotation to `BookmarkRestController` but the same error message remains. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

---

## Edit #1

The classes involved in the problem are the following (copied from my project, not the ones in the tutorial, although the differences are minimal):

### `RestServicesApplication`

```
package com.example.restservices;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import com.example.entity.Account;
import com.example.entity.Bookmark;
import com.example.repository.AccountRepository;
import com.example.repository.BookmarkRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class RestServicesApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(final AccountRepository accountRepository,
            final BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository) {
        return (evt) -> Arrays.asList(
                "jhoeller,dsyer,pwebb,ogierke,rwinch,mfisher,mpollack,jlong".split(","))
                .forEach(
                        a -> {
                            final Account account = accountRepository.save(new Account(a,
                                    "password"));
                            bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
                                    "http://bookmark.com/1/" + a, "A description"));
                            bookmarkRepository.save(new Bookmark(account,
                                    "http://bookmark.com/2/" + a, "A description"));
                        });
    }
}
```

### `BookmarkRestController`

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.repository.AccountRepository;
import com.example.repository.BookmarkRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/{userId}/bookmarks")
public class BookmarkRestController {

    private final BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository;
    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BookmarkRestController(final BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository,
            final AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.bookmarkRepository = bookmarkRepository;
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    // @RequestMapping methods...
}
```

### `AccountRepository`

```
package com.example.repository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.entity.Account;

@Component
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
    Optional<Account> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

### `BookmarkRepository`

```
package com.example.repository;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.entity.Bookmark;

@Component
public interface BookmarkRepository extends JpaRepository<Bookmark, Long> {
    Collection<Bookmark> findByAccountUsername(String username);
}
```

**Note:** I added the imports so you can see where the classes and annotations come from

---

## Edit #2

I tried another thing: I refactored my Project to fit the tutorial and I put everithing in the same package (`com.example.bookmarks`) and removed the extra annotations. The Project compiles but when I run the Project I get a `404` HTTP status when trying to accesss a REST service. I'm still interested in make it run with my original structure but I want to let you know that this refactoring makes the Project work.

Comment: Can you post BookmarkRepository and AccountRepository classes??

Comment: You should mark *Controller classes with @Controller annotation? There is some difference between Service, Component, Controller and Repository annotations. Read spring documentation for detailed explanation.

Comment: @harshavmb both repository classes are the same you can see in the tutorial with the addition of `@org.springframework.stereotype.Component` annotation. `BookmarkRestController` is indeed annotated with `@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController`, which includes `@Controller`

Comment: I won't look at the referenced links/tutorials and you shouldn't expect others to do so on SO. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to improve questioning on SO.

Comment: @harshavmb, please let me disagree with you as I saw my post very clean, minimal, complete and verifiable by describing the problem, the error messages and the things I've done while keeping the code (and the order in which it were added)  separated. However doesn't do any wrong (except to make the post longer) to add the code as you requested, so please check **Edit #1**. Best regards and thanks for your time

Comment: Okay. From both *Repository interfaces, replace Component annotation with Repository annotation. In fact you don't need to specify any annotation as it extends JpaRepository and spring should create the bean. Can you try that???

Comment: Also in BookmarkRestController you are injecting both the repository instances. So, use @Autowired annotation so that spring can inject those instances.

Comment: The error remains the same. I forgot to say that I've already tried by changing the `@Autowired` from the constructor to the fields with no change in the error message

Answer (score 2):

To have Spring create a bean that implements JpaRepository interface, you need to use Spring JPA namespace and activate the repository support using the appropriate element. In xml:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.repository" />
```

In annotation:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
```

See [this docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

This scans all packages below `com.example.repository` for interfaces extending `JpaRepository` and creates a Spring bean for it that is backed by an implementation of [SimpleJpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html).

Comment: Go through this tutorial http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I've followed the tutorial and the only meaningful difference is the `@Transactional` annotation in the repository interface (`application.properties` doesn't matter as I'm facing a DI problem, not a connection one). I've tried both `@javax.transaction.Transactional` and `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` but none of these worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create package again. You packing looking not right. Recreate your package

Comment: Check **Edit #2**, I changed the packages but the services are not working, what were wrong with my packages?