# Spring can't find the specified Bean

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, repository

I have a Spring aplication that uses the JpaRepository to connect to h2, but it's giving the following error:

`Field usuarioRepository in com.julio.demo.DemoApplication required a bean of type 'com.julio.repositories.UsuarioRepository' that could not be found.`

`The injection point has the following annotations:`
`- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)`
`Action:`

`Consider defining a bean of type 'com.julio.repositories.UsuarioRepository' in your configuration.`

I tried this solution and think I have already added this bean in the configuration. Is my @Repository configured correctly? My configuration can be found below:

```
package com.julio.demo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import com.julio.domain.Usuario;
import com.julio.repositories.UsuarioRepository;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Usuario u1 = new Usuario(null, "julio", "julio", "123");
        Usuario u2 = new Usuario(null, "cesar", "cesar", "123");

        usuarioRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(u1,u2));
    
    }

}
```

```
package com.julio.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.julio.domain.Usuario;

@Repository
public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Integer>{

}
```

application properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

here are my dependencies if that helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.julio</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44753122/12940893) help? I believe you need to add the Jpa Repository annotation and dependency

Comment: You aren't following the Spring Boot best practices. Move the repository to the `com.julio.demo.repositories` package instead of `com.julio.repositories`. Remove the `@EnableJpaRepositories` and restart your application. The same applies to all other classes, make them part of the `com.julio.demo` package **or** move the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class to `com.julio` instead of `com.julio.demo` (this would work as well) and remove `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Comment: It worked, thank you. Im new to the community is there a way i can set this comment as the correct answer?

Answer (score -1):

@julinoo You may have to define the basePackage. since the package name is not a standard one, as follows:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.julio.repositories"})
```

Comment: He would need a bunch of other annotations as well, due to not following the recommended packaging structure.

Comment: In fact, I am taking a course, and the instructor is using Eclipse. However, I chose to use VSCode. I'm not sure if this is interfering with anything because I followed all the instructions, but I'm getting this error.